# Setting value of yii2 select2 widget from javascript

Tags: php, yii2, jquery-select2

Is it possible to set certain options as selected in yii2 select2 widget from jquery. The widget is not initialised through js but it is bound to model attribute in form. Any help would be appreciated

Code:

```
echo $form->field($model, 'news_tags')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
                    'data' => ArrayHelper::map(app\models\Topics::findAll(['status' => 1]), 'tp_id', 'title'),
                    'options' => ['multiple' => true, 'placeholder' => 'Select Tags ...'],
                    'pluginOptions' => [
                        'tags' => false,
                        'allowClear' => true
                    ],
                ])->label(FALSE);
```

I am trying to use an ajax call and on succes i want to add some tags from clientside.

Comment: Please share your code or fiddle

Comment: Are you using kartik select2?

Comment: It is possible.put your codes

Comment: Sorry for being late! I'll put the codes rightaway

Comment: Yes! I am using kartik select2.

Comment: Anyone, any help??

Comment: Are you fine with custom jQuery/JavaScript or only with plugin options? I might take a look tomorrow.

Comment: Custom jquery might be fine since I want to add the tags from ajax success. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

As is presented in docs https://select2.github.io/examples.html#programmatic
you can use following code:

```
$("#form-field").val("5").trigger("change");
```

and it will select option, that has id `5`